# Repeat a recursion of a function "x" times

Tags: python, recursion

I need to repeat a function "x" amount of times by recursion. I can do that, but the output needs to carry over for each one.

num is the amount of times to be called

```py
def incr(n):
    print(n+1)
    return n+1

def foo(fn, num):
    def op(n):
        fn(n)
    print(num)
    if(num > 0):
        foo(fn, num-1)

    return op

f = foo(incr, 3)
f(5)
```

Right now I get 6. The intended result is 6,7,8

Comment: I'm not sure this is optimal, what are you exactly after? What do you want to achieve with your function? This returns me 3,2,1,0,6. Not only 6.

Comment: what is `6,7,8`, a `tuple`?

Comment: `f()` (which is `op()`) is not a recursive function, it invokes `fn` once, and that is all. `foo()` is a recursive function, and I would expect it to display 3,2,1 prior to its return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
def incr(n):
    print(n+1)
    return n+1

def foo(fn, num):
    def op(n):
        if num > 0:
            n = fn(n)
            foo(fn, num-1)(n)
    return op

f = foo(incr, 3)
f(5)
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply!

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function should call itself, see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-functions/ for more.

I also added a parameter that keeps track of the end result.

```
def incr(n, num):
  if (n != num):
    print(n + 1)
    return incr(n + 1, num)

def foo(fn, num):
  def op(n):
    fn(n, n + num)
  return op

f = foo(incr, 3)
f(5)
```